# Ruby: Copy contents of folder in zipfile

Tags: ruby, zip

There is a zipfile. It can either have 10 files or one folder. This folder will have the 10 files. Now, if the zipfile has a folder, then i have to move all the files one directory above i.e.

zipfile.zip has folder. folder has 10 files. normally, if i unzip, i get zipfile/folder/10files. Now, I have to get like zipfile/10files. ie. move all the files one directory above.

How to do this? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind using Linux `unzip` and really aren't worried about subdirectories:

```
def unzip(file)
  to = File.join(File.dirname(file), File.basename(file, ".*"))
  Dir.mkdir(to) unless File.exists?(to)
  `unzip -j #{file} -d #{to}`
end
# unzip('yourfile.zip')
```

This method creates a new directory in the same directory as the zip file with the same name as the zipfile (minus extension). It then extracts (using `unzip`) the zip file into that directory, ignoring all paths (the `-j` flag tells `unzip` to junk paths).

**EDIT**

Per your comment, here is a way to do it without system calls:

```
def unzip(file)
  Zip::ZipFile.open(file) do |zipfile|
    to = File.join(File.dirname(file), File.basename(file, ".*"))
    FileUtils.mkdir(to) unless File.exists? to
    zipfile.each do |f|
      if f.file? # Don't extract directories
        fpath = File.join(to, File.basename(f.name))
        zipfile.extract(f, fpath) unless File.exists?(fpath)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I want to do it using Ruby library calls only. No system calls.

Comment: I've updated my answer with an alternative not using system calls.